# MySQL - CASE WHEN, a terceira condição não retorna o THEN

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz a `QUERY` um CASE para exibir na saída 'Data' se está **vigente**, **expirada** ou **pendente**, mas para pendente não tem saída quando printa.

```
$sql_check_plano = "SELECT 
    *,
    (
    SELECT 
        `ps_nome` 
    FROM 
        `plano_pack` 
    WHERE 
        `ps_token` = `pu_ps_token` 
    LIMIT 
        1
    ) AS `plano_nome`,
    (
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN 
                TIMEDIFF(`pu_data_expira`,NOW()) < 0 THEN 'Expirado' 
            WHEN 
                TIMEDIFF(`pu_data_expira`,NOW()) > 0 THEN 'Vigente' 
            WHEN 
                `pu_data_expira` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN 'Pendente'
        END
    ) AS `Data`
FROM 
    `plano_usuario` 
WHERE 
    `pu_user_token` = '" . $_SESSION['usuario']['user_token'] . "' 
ORDER BY 
    `pu_data_cad` 
        DESC 
;";
```

Comment: Você verificou se NO_ZERO_DATE mode está habilitado em suas configurações? Se estiver teste com IS NULL.

Comment: na migração que vem para o ambiente de produção não sei como estará as configurações, então estou evitando usar recursos que dependem de configuração personalizada, mas funcionou como você sugeriu, esse no_zero_date desconhecia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inseri na condição que a data também seja diferente de "000-00-00 00:00:00" e se não for < ou > então é uma data não definida, então inseri o ELSE 'Pendente', não sei se é a melhor solução, mas retornou como esperado.

```
$sql_check_plano = "SELECT 
    *,
    TIMEDIFF(`pu_data_expira`,NOW()) AS xxx,
    (
    SELECT 
        `ps_nome` 
    FROM 
        `plano_pack` 
    WHERE 
        `ps_token` = `pu_ps_token` 
    LIMIT 
        1
    ) AS `plano_nome`,
    (
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN 
                TIMEDIFF(`pu_data_expira`,NOW()) < 0 AND `pu_data_expira` != '0000-0000-00 00:00:00' THEN 'Expirado' 
            WHEN 
                TIMEDIFF(`pu_data_expira`,NOW()) > 0 AND `pu_data_expira` != '0000-0000-00 00:00:00' THEN 'Vigente' 
            ELSE 'Pendente'
        END
    ) AS `Data`
FROM 
    `plano_usuario` 
WHERE 
    `pu_user_token` = '" . $_SESSION['usuario']['user_token'] . "' 
ORDER BY 
    `pu_data_cad` 
        DESC 
;";
```